# Access Data from Amazon Web Services(AWS) through salesforce

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce

I am new to development of salesforce.I want to call web services of Amazon. i have created bucket in Amazon S3. Now if i want to fetch data from Amazon S3, how it is possible through **Salesforce**??Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [Force.com Toolkit for Amazon Web Services](http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/global-solution-providers/salesforce/) is probably what you need.  Have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But I have already installed the toolkit..and i have no idea about how to write our code in it.. like which file should modified etc..

Comment: And have you looked at the tutorial for using it?  http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Using_Force_for_Amazon_Web_Services